# How to declared method in Java generically, operating on interface of several subtypes?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have the following

Interface:

```
public interface General {...}
```

Then, couple of implementations of that interface:

```
public class Specific1 implements General {...}

public class Specific2 implements General {...}
```

Then, I have a utility method that needs to combine 2 lists of either:

```
List<Specific1> list1 = ...;
List<Specific1> list2 = ...;
List<Specific1> mergedList = mergeLists(list1, list2);
```

OR:

```
List<Specific2> list1 = ...;
List<Specific2> list2 = ...;
List<Specific2> mergedList = mergeLists(list1, list2);
```

I then have to perform something like this: `pojo.setSpecific1List(mergedList)`, which doesn't allow me to declare my `mergedList` as `List<General> mergedList`.

Question is: how do I declared the `mergeLists` method generically? Is it possible given what I need to do with the returned value?

Comment: Have a look at *generic methods*: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Comment: `<T extends General> List<T> mergeLists(List<T> list1, List<T> list2)`

Comment: What does `mergeList` actually do? Does it just add the contents of one list to the end of the other list? Depends on what it actually does, you can actually make it a _lot_ more general.

Comment: @Sweeper The `mergeList` filters certain items out of one of the lists and then merges the two lists together with `ListUtils.union` (from `org.apache commons.collections4`)

Comment: @shmosel Works! Thank you! Write it up as an answer so I can give you credit.